# We have to read an xml file and convert it into csv file and then store it in the path provided by the user

Tags: java, xml

Write a Java program where user needs to provide the path to a file system (Folder) and then he needs to provide filename. If user provides file name other than “order.xml”, it should throw exception. Program will read the file provided by user and it’ll create a csv file and store it on the same path with filename as order_output.csv.

Create a folder in C drive:

Create a file: order.xml in the above folder

Sample XML file that should be used:

In the order_output.csv, you should have following attributes from the XML

· Column1: OrderNo

· Column2: OrderDate (this field should be added in the CSV as format DD-MM-YYYY)

· Column3: PrimeLineNo

· Column4: SwatchFulfillmentType

· Column5: ExtnSwatchItemID

· Column6: FirstName

· Column7: ExtnAddressLine1

· Column8: ZipCode

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 1):

1. Choose if you wanna use CLI or GUI

Then let's begin:
To check if the file is a .xml you could check the last four char of the file name (the last four are the extension (".xml")).

```
   String#substring(string.length-4) //Get the substring of the given one from last four chars
```

Now check it with an if statement

```
  if(substring == ".xml"){
        //stuff here
  }
```

Now you should read the file with a XML Parser (as [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/)).
After that you have to write the content on the text file (CSV, as you sure know, it's just a text file whose words are separated by comma or semicolon)